# Opening WSL terminal in current VSCode directory without using VSCode server

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've used Git Bash for most bash-required tasks before, but since I've found WSL to be much more feature-rich as it's basically an entirely new subsystem. However, when I used to use VSCode along with Git Bash, it would simply cd into the working directory of the project for ease of use. However, it doesn't do that here. The only solutions I've found online are to create an entirely new Remote WSL VSCode window, but this is way too high maintenance for what I'm trying to do as I'm literally just trying to get VSCode to automatically cd into the correct directory. Thanks in advance.